# Macro excel to create new sheets with names based on a list BUT if repeated do not create

Tags: list, excel, conditional-statements, createprocess, vba

I am able to create sheets including its name based on a selected list of "names" with the following code (below), BUT when there are cells with repeated name it will create a sheet without a name and the generic "sheet##". I want that if the cell name is repeated or there is a sheet already with that name (same thing) NOT to create a new sheet.

```
Sub AddSheets()
Dim cell As Excel.Range
Dim wbToAddSheetsTo As Excel.Workbook

Set wbToAddSheetsTo = ActiveWorkbook
For Each cell In Selection
With wbToAddSheetsTo
    .Sheets.Add after:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveSheet.Name = cell.Value
    If Err.Number = 1004 Then
      Debug.Print cell.Value & " already used as a sheet name"
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to see if the worksheet exists before creating it:

```
Public Function WorkSheetExists(SheetName As String, wrkbk As Workbook) As Boolean
    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
        Set wrkSht = wrkbk.Worksheets(SheetName) 'Attempt to set reference to worksheet.
        WorkSheetExists = (Err.Number = 0) 'Was an error generated - True or False?
        Set wrkSht = Nothing
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Then in your code just check if it exists before creating it:

```
Sub AddSheets()
    Dim cell As Excel.Range
    Dim wbToAddSheetsTo As Excel.Workbook

    Set wbToAddSheetsTo = ActiveWorkbook
    For Each cell In Selection
        **If Not (WorkSheetExists(cell.Value, wbToAddSheetsTo)) Then**
            With wbToAddSheetsTo
                .Sheets.Add after:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
                On Error Resume Next
                ActiveSheet.Name = cell.Value
                If Err.Number = 1004 Then
                  Debug.Print cell.Value & " already used as a sheet name"
                End If
                On Error GoTo 0
            End With
        **End If**
    Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! for your answer, ... the sheets dont exist before, the problem is when it creates them because there are repeated "names" in the cells selection, it will create the first one fine, but the next (if repeated) will create the sheet "sheet##" which I dont need. Taking into account that I cannot take the repeated ones from the selection because this will be the source for other parts of the code I am creating... should I add the worksheetexists inside the code?

Comment: Yes, add the WorkSheetExists function either in a separate module, or its own module (not a worksheet or ThisWorkbook module). Then add the two lines (with an * at either end) into your code.

It will then work through your list - with the first 'name' it will check if it exists, which it doesn't so it will allow the sheet to be created.  When it gets to a duplicate name it will check to see if it exists again - this time it does so it won't allow the sheet to be created - error 1004 will never happen as it checks beforehand.

Comment: Great! I am working on it. (i am new at this) thanks!